# Реализация Event

Tags: c#, .net, события

При помощи ILSpy, гугла и десятка-другого нецензурных слов, мне удалось точно воспроизвести реализацию методов `Add` и `Remove` стандартного `event`.

В итоге код события выглядит так, во всяком случае после компиляции в Release, IL-код получается эквивалентным на 100%. В Debug - он естественно отличается, но незначительно, а именно в части проверки условия цикла.

```
//field-like объявление события
public event Action SampleEvent1;

//итоги декомпиляции
private Action eventDelegate;
public event Action SampleEvent2
{
    add
    {
        Action current = eventDelegate, 
        Action comparer;
        do
        {
            comparer = current;
            Action combine = comparer + value;
            current = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref eventDelegate, combine, comparer);
        }
        while (!object.ReferenceEquals(current, comparer));
    }
    remove
    {
        Action current = eventDelegate, 
        Action comparer;
        do
        {
            comparer = current;
            Action combine = comparer - value;
            current = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref eventDelegate, combine, comparer);
        }
        while (!object.ReferenceEquals(current, comparer));
    }
}
```

А теперь вопрос знатокам: я понимаю что это все нужно для поддержки многопоточности и что использование `lock` может приводить к взаимным блокировкам, но я не до конца понимаю как и, самое главное, почему работает этот вариант.

Comment: А точно current не обновляется на каждой итерации? Это выглядит как стандартное lock-free-обновление.

Comment: @VladD current - обновляется, только InvokeList из основного делегата в него передается всего один раз перед циклом, меня это тоже сразу смутило, но потом по тестировал и сравнил код с оригиналом - все так.

Comment: А, точно, compareexchange! Понял. Я напишу, когда доберусь до компьютера, если никто раньше не напишет.

Comment: Добавлю-ка я пару полезных ссылок по теме: [Сравнение с обменом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Сравнение_с_обменом), [Неблокирующая синхронизация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Неблокирующая_синхронизация).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Смотрите.

Подписка на/отписка от событий должны быть атомарными, чтобы не было возможно, что кто-то подписался, а событие не приходит. Старые версии делали блокировку:

```
private EventHandler _myEvent;        
public event EventHandler MyEvent
{
    add { lock (this) _myEvent += value; }
    remove { lock (this) _myEvent -= value; }        
}
```

Недостаток этого метода — блокировка требует объекта, а какой объект брать? Можно взять «невидимый» объект, но этот объект должен быть тогда как-то специфицирован в стандарте и доступен для использования (например, если мы хотим под той же блокировкой прочитать значение делегата), что не так уж и хорошо, поскольку предписывает деталь имплементации. Поэтому используется `this`.

Но `this` в свою очередь ведёт к другой проблеме: он может быть заблокирован снаружи, кем угодно! Поэтому было решено отказаться от этой идеи, и перейти к неблокирующему (lock-free) алгоритму, который не требует блокировочного объекта, и вдобавок ко всему просто быстрее и эффективнее.

---

Как это работает? А вот как. Переименую немного переменные:

```
Action eventDelegate;

public void AddSampleEvent1(Action value)
{
    Action current = eventDelegate;
    Action noncombined;
    do
    {
        noncombined = current;
        Action combined = (Action)Delegate.Combine(noncombined, value);
        current = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref eventDelegate, combined, noncombined);
    }
    while (current != noncombined);
}
```

Если посмотреть, [что делает `Interlocked.CompareExchange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb297966(v=vs.110).aspx), это можно переписать для ясности так:

```
Action eventDelegate;

public void AddSampleEvent1(Action value)
{
    Action current = eventDelegate;
    Action noncombined;
    do
    {
        noncombined = current;
        Action combined = (Action)Delegate.Combine(noncombined, value);
        atomic // фиктивное ключевое слово
        {
            if (noncombined == eventDelegate)
                eventDelegate = combined;
            current = eventDelegate;
        }
    }
    while (current != noncombined);
}
```

Что происходит? В `current` на начало итерации цикла будет значение `eventDelegate`. Мы запоминаем его во временную переменную `noncombined`, и добавляем `value`, получая делегат `combined`. Теперь мы пытаемся записать результат назад. Если в этой точке наш делегат никто не успел поменять из другого потока (а так скорее всего и будет), то `Interlocked.CompareExchange` завершится успешно, запишет делегат на место, и в `current` будет старое значение делегата. Это завершит цикл, проверка `current != noncombined` даст `false`.

Если же пока мы пытались комбинировать, другой поток изменил `eventDelegate`, то проверка условия в `Interlocked.CompareExchange` завершится неуспешно. В этом случае в `eventDelegate` нельзя ничего писать, ведь мы потеряем изменённое значение! Тогда мы просто записываем это новое значение в `current` и уходим на следующую итерацию (проверка `current != noncombined` даст `true`). На следующей итерации мы сделаем то же самое: с текущим значением `eventDelegate` попробуем скомбинировать новый делегат, и записать на место, проверяя при этом, никто ли не поменял тем временем `eventDelegate` снова. Это по идее типичная неблокирующая техника, я видел много подобного кода в неблокирующих алгоритмах.

Comment: не, с этим моментом я как раз разобрался, у Скита на EnSO читал. Я не понимаю как текущий вариант обеспечивает безопасность для потоков %) может плохо искал, но описания не нашел.

Comment: @rdorn: Ага, я допишу, это я «застолбил» ответ :)

Comment: @rdorn: У меня, кажется, выходит другой код после «сборки» IL. Перепроверяю.

Comment: Ближе к вечеру могу выложить скрины стандартного и моего методов из ILSpy. LiNQPad дает не совсем корректный результат, он не делает оптимизации как студия при релизе. За другие средства не знаю, пока работаю только с этими тремя.

Comment: @rdorn: Я пошёл через ILDasm/ILAsm, сейчас перепроверяю.

Comment: @rdorn: Окей, ваш код совпадает с тем, что выдаёт ILSpy. Смотрю дальше.

Comment: а что делает `Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref eventDelegate, combine, comparer);`? Он что с чем меняет? и возвращает?

Comment: @Grundy если ref параметр совпадает с comparer, то в ref кладется новое значение из combine, а старое из ref возвращается как результат.

Comment: @rdorn, ага, уже тоже глянул, но не совсем пойму как он с Action работает :)

Comment: @Grundy он сравнивает и меняет InvocationList-ы Action-ов. Тестовый код для этого легко пишется, если надо могу добавить в вопрос. А остальное для меня пока загадка, и ночь как на зло полдня как закончилась =)

Comment: @rdorn: А, разобрался. Сейчас :)

Comment: @rdorn: Написал, смотрите.

Comment: @VladD т.е. по факту, всю безопасность обеспечивает атомарность Interlocked.CompareExchange, а все остальное - служебный обвес для его работы? Ну Ок, появится время, полезу глубже, ну не люблю я когда машина делает что-то чего я не понимаю, вот расковыриваю по маленьку =)

Comment: @rdorn: Да. `Interlocked.CompareExchange` — это известный примитив для неблокирующих операций. Основная идея: запомнить предыдущее значение, сделать что-то, и при помощи `Interlocked.CompareExchange` попытаться записать назад с проверкой, не поменял ли кто значение тем временем. При неудаче откатиться и повторить.

Comment: @VladD Спасибо, как всегда подробно и человеческим языком =) Буду думать где еще смогу это применить, сейчас как раз проект подходящий для этого в работе.

Comment: @VladD, проверь редакцию, не уверен, что вставленное слово это то, что ты имел ввиду.

Comment: @rdorn: Пожалуйста! И спасибо за интересный вопрос.

Comment: @Grundy: Да, именно то, что надо, спасибо!